# Why is the image for the new SE blog misaligned when the message one-boxes?

Tags: bug, chat, design, blog

[image]

I would've gone for some freehand if there already weren't outlined with the help of the SE chat UI. As you can see, the image is misaligned, and thus [intrudes](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4021918#4021918) the realm of the next message.

So, why does it happen? Is a fix coming or have we found a way to surprise people in other SE chatrooms?

Comment: The cat was faster than you.

Comment: @Sha shame on me.